# AllowUsers with nothing following it in sshd_config file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh, sshd

I have no way of testing this and can't find the answer online. If I put `AllowUsers` in my sshd_config file with nothing following it would the behavior be to allow everyone to SSH into the computer, or to deny everyone?

Example:

```
// all of sshd_conf file...

AllowUsers
```

Comment: Why don't you setup a VM? You will be able to test it yourself, then.

Comment: this may help from man sshd_config " This keyword **can** be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by spaces.  If specified, login is allowed only for user names that match one of the patterns......By default, login is allowed for all users."   <-- so I guess maybe the man page is saying that it'd not allow anybody if you did dthat.

Comment: @bwDraco the man page uses the word "can". as if to say you don't have to specify one or more users

Answer (score 1):

> If I put `AllowUsers` in my sshd_config file with nothing following it would the behavior be to allow everyone to SSH into the computer, or to deny everyone?

It is so hard to try?

```
echo "AllowUsers" > /etc/ssh/sshd_config
systemctl restart sshd
systemctl status sshd # no error
ssh user@localhost # succeed
```

So yes, you can put there `AllowUsers` option without argument and it will behave like there would be no option (all users will be allowed, if you don't specify any `DenyUsers` or any `AllowUsers` before).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to test sshd_config file is to use the flag `-T`:

```
user@machine:~$ echo "Allowusers" > sshd_config
user@machine:~$ sshd -T -f sshd_config
sshd_config line 1: no argument after keyword "Allowusers"
sshd_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

Despite the previous answer, it appears that the option `AllowUsers` with no users is not allowed.
A solution if you must use this option, would be to use the pattern `!*` (deny all users) or `*` (allow all users):

```
user@machine:~$ echo "Allowusers !*" > sshd_config
user@machine:~$ sshd -T -f sshd_config
user@machine:~$
```